# php sort properties of object

Tags: php, sorting, object

I want to sort the properties of an object so I can loop through them in a defined order.

for example: I have an object 'book' with the following properties: 'id', 'title', 'author', 'date'.

Now i want to loop through these properties like this:

```
foreach($book as $prop=>$val)
//do something
```

now the order of the loop has to be 'title', then 'author', 'date' and 'id'

How would one do this?
(I can't change the order of the properties in the class of the object because there arent any properties defined there, I get the object from the database with 'MyActiveRecord')

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure if this answers to your question, but you could try :

```
$properties = array('title', 'author', 'date', 'id');
foreach ($properties as $prop) {
    echo $book->$prop;
}
```

Alternatively, you could extract the properties of the book (instead of hardcoding them), and sort them with your custom order :

```
$props = get_class_vars(get_class($book));
uasort($props, 'my_properties_sorting_function');
```

Comment: Ok thx, I went for the array of properties and looping through them, seems the simplest answer to me ;)

Answer (score 4):

You could wrap your source object into something that implements the [Iterator interface](http://docs.php.net/class.iterator) and returns the properties of the source object in a given sort order.

```
class Foo implements Iterator {
  protected $src;
  protected $order;
  protected $valid;

  public function __construct(/*object*/ $source, array $sortorder) {
    $this->src = $source;
    $this->order = $sortorder;
    $this->valid = !empty($this->order);
  }
  public function current() { return $this->src->{current($this->order)}; }
  public function key() { return key($this->order); }
  public function next() { $this->valid = false!==next($this->order); }
  public function rewind() { reset($this->order); $this->valid = !empty($this->order); }

  public function valid() { return $this->valid; }
}

class Book {
  public $id='idval';
  public $author='authorval';
  public $date='dateval';
  public $title='titleval';
}


function doSomething($it) {
  foreach($it as $p) {  
    echo '  ', $p, "\n";
  }
}

$book = new Book;
echo "passing \$book to doSomething: \n";
doSomething($book);

$it = new Foo($book, array('title', 'author', 'date', 'id'));
echo "passing \$it to doSomething: \n";
doSomething($it);
```

prints

```
passing $book to doSomething: 
  idval
  authorval
  dateval
  titleval
passing $it to doSomething: 
  titleval
  authorval
  dateval
  idval
```

Comment: much more complicated than my answer, but much more object-oriented, smart and reusable. +1

Comment: and also slower than your version. The SPL isn't the fastest gun in all PHP land ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Try this. The difference between this method and the method proposed in the first response is that the method **get_class_vars** returns **default** properties of the class, whereas **get_object_vars** returns the properties of the **given** object.

```
<?php

class Book {
  public $title;
  public $author;
  public $date;
  public $id;
}

  $b = new Book();
  $b->title = "title";

  $object_vars = get_object_vars($b);
  ksort($object_vars);

  foreach($object_vars as $prop=>$val)
        echo $prop."->".$val."<br>";

?>
```

Comment: This does not achieve the requested order.