# reorder object based on an array

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have an object that looks like this:

### EDIT snippet with example

https://3v4l.org/vRZUR

output of `var_dump($registerObject)`:

```
{#822 ▼
  +"Sleutel": 1
  +"Gebouw_ID": "20250043814"
  +"Toestel_ID": "BE071   (S035)"
  ...
  +"date": "2019-03-22 08:52:39"
  +"status": 1
  +"done": 0
}
```

I need to reorden this object to match this arrays order:

```
$order = [
        0 => 'object_id',
        1 => 'Code MCS',
        2 => 'DeviceType',
        ...
        29 => '',
        30 => 'Opmerkingen',
        31 => 'OPMonderhoud',
    ];
```

this is what I've tried;

I cast the object to an array than I use an uksort on the array and use the order array and I combine this with an array_search to sort the array.

I think I am close but I am not sure what is going wrong.

```
$registerArray = (array) $registerObject;

uksort($registerArray, function ($a, $b) use ($order) {
    return array_search($a, $order) > array_search($b, $order);
});
```

this returns in a weird order:

```
array:28 [▼
  "done" => 0
  "Voedingskast" => ""
  "status" => 1
  ...
  "action" => "create"
  "sleutel" => 1
  "OPMonderhoud" => ""
]
```

I've also tried doing the $order array with values only without keys, it gives the same result.

Comment: Your approach seem valid - this simple example works https://3v4l.org/d1XDp - can you please provide short code that reproduce your problem?

Comment: @dWinder here it is https://3v4l.org/vRZUR

Comment: What do you mean by "reorder object"? I've never heard of an options that sorts the properties

Comment: @NicoHaase the object needs to look like the order array exactly the same with the empty values also

Comment: So, what **exactly** is the question? If you cast that object to an array, you can sort it however you like. If it stays an object, what's the need to sort the properties?

Comment: the question is how to I sort the properties like the order array with the empty entries also

Comment: @NicoHaase open the code snippet you'll understand better I think

Comment: Please add all relevant information to the question, don't hide them behind links to external pages. Additionally, the code snippet does not contain any object; neither does it contain anything to create the first vardump output

Comment: @NicoHaase the question is very clear in my opinion, I don't know how to make it more clear. Suggestions are welcome

Comment: You could start by providing the proper code you're currently using, and a clear description of your problem. What's the real requirement you try to meet? Ordering the properties of an object should not matter

Comment: @NicoHaase unfortunately "Ordering the properties of an object should not matter" is exactly my requirement that's only thing i try to do here :D

Comment: So, in the end, you want to write a single piece of software that orders properties in any random object?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942906/php-sort-properties-of-object help?

Answer (score 0):

This is because some keys do not exist in `$order` so it is comparing `false` to integers.

This produces the expected result:

```
uksort($registerArray, function ($a, $b) use ($order) {
     $ai = array_search($a, $order);
     $bi = array_search($b, $order);
     return ($ai === false ? INF : $ai) > ($bi === false ? INF : $bi);
});
```

https://3v4l.org/rPh8t

---

Update per comments:

If empty spots are desired, then it can no longer be an Associative array, can't have multiple identical keys; has to be Numeric.

```
$newArray = array();
foreach ($order as $k) {
    if (array_key_exists($k, $registerArray)) {
        $newArray[] = $registerArray[$k];
    } else {
        $newArray[] = '';
    }
}
```

https://3v4l.org/NEetX

Comment: thanks for your answer but it's not right if you look in the $order array there should be 7 empty key betwen the keys "omschrijving" and "Onderhoudsfirma" this is not the case in your code snippet

Comment: @Michael if you're expecting this then `uksort()` is not the proper function to use. Stand by and I'll make a fresh one which I think might be closer to what you're looking for...